# Can't set state object using action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

I have a product list and form on my vue application.  When the product list is opened, a request is made to my rest api and fills the results in a pinia store object (`products`).  This works great so far and the products get added to my state.

I can also request a single product using my api by passing the `product_id` to it.  This is how I handled the product form at first, but realized it would be more efficient to filter the `products` store object and get the single product from state rather than make another api request when the form component loads.  I created a new action to do just this but I can't get it to work.  Here is my store with the action:

```js
//ProductStore.js

import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { getProducts } from "@/composables/products";

export const useProductStore = defineStore("product", {
  state: () => ({
    products: [], //for my products list component
    product: {}, //for my product form component
    attributes: [],
    loading: false,
    error: "",
  }),
  actions: {
    findProduct(id) { //find single product in store
      this.product = this.products.find((product) => product.id === id);
    },
    async fetchProducts() { // retrieve all products from api
      this.loading = true;
      const { products, error } = await getProducts(); //api call
     
      this.products = products;
      this.error = error;
      this.loading = false;

    },
  }
});
```

Here is my product form component I'm trying to filter the `products` store to get a single `product` and bind with the form:

```js
// ProductForm.vue

<template>
 <input v-model="product.name" class="input" type="text" />
 <input v-model="product.desc" class="input" type="text" />
</template>

<script setup>
  import { onMounted } from "vue";
  import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";
  import { useProductStore } from "@/stores/ProductStore";
  
  const props = defineProps({
    id: String,
  });

  const store = useProductStore();
  const { product, error, loading } = storeToRefs(store);

  onMounted(() => {

    store.findProduct(props.id);
    console.log(product);

  });
  
</script>
```

When I `console.log(product)` it appears I get the ref() to the product store object but without the value property:

[image]

When I run all of this I get the error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $setup.product is undefined`

I'm completely aware this is due to my poverty of knowledge with vue 3 composition API and pinia.  I can't figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think I figured it out...  in my `ProductForm` component I was bringing in the prop for the `product_id`:

```js
const props = defineProps({
    id: String,
  });
```

And I was invoking my action like this:

```js
store.findProduct(props.id);
```

I started wondering if the prop being a string (since it comes from url) was causing the issue.  So I used:

```js
store.findProduct(parseInt(props.id));
```

which immediately returned the single product into my component.  So I ended up modifying my routes file to handle the parse for me:

```js
//  @/routes/index.js

{
  name: "Product",
  path: "/products/:id",
  component: () => import("@/components/ProductForm"),
  props: route => ({ id: Number(route.params.id) }),
},
```